# mapreduce issue in eclipse

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I get this issue when I run WordCount in eclipse.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:808)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1297)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1315)
    at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:81)
```

Any ideas on where the problem might be?

Comment: Are you trying to launch this job on a cluster from within Eclipse?

Comment: No. Just want run any MR program in eclipse with small dataset.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add these [winutils](https://github.com/sardetushar/hadooponwindows/archive/master.zip) files  to your `$HADOOP_HOME/bin` folder.

Comment: How do you know OP is using Windows?

Comment: I got the same error when I was building local eclipse env on windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add few jars from your hadoop-version/share/hadoop folder to run the program in eclipse locally on a linux machine.

```
Hadoop common 1.2.1 jar
```

You need to download the above jar file separately. You can follow the below blog link to know the complete procedure.

https://acadgild.com/blog/running-mapreduce-in-local-mode-2/